# How to determine document color mode with Vbscript

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-scripting, vbscript

What is Vbscript syntax to determine document color mode?

### Regards to the posted answer:

I figured it out. Basically the same as your codes. I did not enumerate like you did. I was just interested in getting the returned long value.

So mine was:

```
Dim mode as long Dim ObjApp

    set objApp = CreateObject("Photoshop.Application") mode = objApp.Activedocument.mode Rem ---------- Immediate test ---------- debug.print mode
```

I like your enumeration technique. I will put it to use.

Comment: 1) It appears you have two accounts and that is frowned upon, please contact SE to have both merged. 2) This is a question and answer site, if you would like to discuss beyond the answer please take that to [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/the-ink-spot). 3) if you did use some parts of his answer it is customary to accept his answer so he can get his due rep for helping. By doing so that encourages people to answer your question. Beyond that I've edited your question to include the removed answer you provided.

Comment: Sorry about that. I was asked to create a new account whne I tried to post a question. How can I contact SE to merge my accounts?

Comment: [Contact](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/contact).

Answer (score 1):

Syntax does not mean what you think it means. There is no syntax for determining color mode. But yeah document objects have a property that is surprisingly named 'Mode'.

```
dim app

set app = CreateObject( "Photoshop.Application" )

dim msg
dim mode
dim niceNames
niceNames = Array(_
   "","Grayscale","RGB","CMYK","Lab","Bitmap",_
   "Indexed","MultiChannel", "Duotone")

mode = app.ActiveDocument.Mode 
msg = mode & " means color mode is: " & niceNames(mode)
MsgBox(msg )
```

Names subject to change form Photoshop version to other.